# why such increase in viewstate size

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a large web forms page with multiple user made controls in it (.ascx). One control gives me a very big increase in _VIEWSTATE elements, without it there are around a 1000 _VIEWSTATE occurrences and with it - around 7000. This freezes browser as it tries to parse the viewstate.

The problematic user control is UpdatePanel with Repeater in it, ItemTemplate has some Eval's, HiddenFields, DropDowns, TextBoxes, nothing too special but around 50 rows of repeater gives new 6000 _VIEWSTATE elements. Maybe any ideas why? Or how to decrease this viewstate?

Comment: Set `EnableViewState="false"` to as many controls as possible. Especially Repeater, GridView, ListView Controls.

Comment: @VDWWD this does decrease viewstate, however saving changes no longer working

Comment: I know, but it can be done. But it requires restructuring your code behind and the way you bind data. For starters you have to get rid of the IsPostBack check on many controls. It takes some getting used to, but once you disable viewstate, the site will be faster and have less data transmitted.